# Navbar content not displaying properly

Tags: html, css

Hello I'm trying to style my navbar and have everything aligned properly, but I'm not sure what is making my nav content display like this. Also, how can I remove the grey box next to my nav brand? I messed around with it on the inspect elements, but I don't know how to get rid of it. I have provided my code below. Thanks!

When bs css link isn't added (How I want to keep it):

[image]

When bs css link is added:

[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Dashboard UI </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

  

</head>
<body>
<!---Navbar--->
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a style="font-size: 45px; color: #A388E7;" class="navbar-brand" href="#"><strong>StudioPick</a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-curresnt="page" href="index.html">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item2">
                <div class="action">
                  <div class="profile" onclick="menuToggle();">
                    <img src="./assets/avatar.jpg" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <h3 id="profile-name"><strong>User Name</strong></h3>
                    <p class="text-muted" id="userType" style="position: relative; top: -20px; right: -60px; font-size: 12px !important">Studio</p>
                    <ul>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/user.png" /><a href="studiodash.html">Dashboard</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/edit.png" /><a href="editprofile.html">Edit profile</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/envelope.png" /><a href="#">Inbox</a>
                      </li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/settings.png" /><a href="#">Setting</a>
                      </li>
                      <li><img src="./assets/icons/question.png" /><a href="#">Help</a></li>
                      <li>
                        <img src="./assets/icons/log-out.png" /><a href="#" onclick="signOut();">Logout</a>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <!---Navbar--->
<main class="main">
    <div class="responsive-wrapper">
        <div class="main-header">
            <h1>Settings</h1>
            <div class="search">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
                <button type="submit">
                    <i class="ph-magnifying-glass-bold"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="horizontal-tabs">
            <a href="#">My details</a>
            <a href="#">Profile</a>
            <a href="#">Password</a>
            <a href="#">Team</a>
            <a href="#">Plan</a>
            <a href="#">Billing</a>
            <a href="#">Email</a>
            <a href="#">Notifications</a>
            <a href="#" class="active">Integrations</a>
            <a href="#">API</a>
        </div>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="content-header-intro">
                <h2>Intergrations and connected apps</h2>
                <p>Supercharge your workflow and connect the tool you use every day.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="content-header-actions">
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-faders-bold"></i>
                    <span>Filters</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="button">
                    <i class="ph-plus-bold"></i>
                    <span>Request integration</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="content-panel">
                <div class="vertical-tabs">
                    <a href="#" class="active">View all</a>
                    <a href="#">Developer tools</a>
                    <a href="#">Communication</a>
                    <a href="#">Productivity</a>
                    <a href="#">Browser tools</a>
                    <a href="#">Marketplace</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content-main">
                <div class="card-grid">
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/zeplin.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Zeplin</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Collaboration between designers and developers.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/github.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>GitHub</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Link pull requests and automate workflows.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                    <article class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            <div>
                                <span><img src="https://assets.codepen.io/285131/figma.svg" /></span>
                                <h3>Figma</h3>
                            </div>
                            <label class="toggle">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                                <span></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p>Embed file previews in projects.</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#">View integration</a>
                        </div>
                    </article>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://unpkg.com/phosphor-icons'></script><script  src="./script.js"></script>

  <script>
    function menuToggle() {
      const toggleMenu = document.querySelector(".menu");
      toggleMenu.classList.toggle("active");
    }
  </script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!----More Bootstrap--->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Be+Vietnam+Pro:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap");
:root {
  --c-text-primary: #282a32;
  --c-text-secondary: #686b87;
  --c-text-action: #404089;
  --c-accent-primary: #434ce8;
  --c-border-primary: #eff1f6;
  --c-background-primary: #ffffff;
  --c-background-secondary: #fdfcff;
  --c-background-tertiary: #ecf3fe;
  --c-background-quaternary: #e9ecf4;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  min-height: 100vh;
  font-family: "Be Vietnam Pro", sans-serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5 !important;
  color: var(--c-text-primary);
}


:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #A388E7 !important;
  font-weight: bolder;
  padding-top: 0.3125rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.3125rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav-item{
  color: #686868 !important;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  right: -1675px !important;
}
.nav-item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out;
}

#alert{
  position: relative;
  right: -3px !important;
}

.action {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
}

.action .profile {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.action .profile img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.action .menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: -10px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: 0.5s;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  
}

.action .menu.active {
  top: 80px;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 28px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.action .menu h3 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #555;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

.action .menu h3 span {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #cecece;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.action .menu ul li {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 16px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.action .menu ul li img {
  max-width: 20px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.action .menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #555;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.action .menu ul li:hover a {
  color: #9370DB;
}


.responsive-wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1280px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.button {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  line-height: 1;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
}
.button i {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 1.25em;
}
.button span {
  font-weight: 500;
}
.button:hover, .button:focus {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}



.main {
  padding-top: 3rem;
}

.main-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.main-header h1 {
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.25;
}
@media (max-width: 550px) {
  .main-header h1 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
  }
}

.search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}
.search input {
  font: inherit;
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 1em 0 36px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 2px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
}
.search input::-moz-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input::placeholder {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
}
.search input:focus, .search input:hover {
  border-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.search button {
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.25em;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
}

.horizontal-tabs {
  margin-top: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .horizontal-tabs {
    scrollbar-width: none;
    position: relative;
  }
  .horizontal-tabs::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }
}
.horizontal-tabs a {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  align-items: center;
  height: 48px;
  padding: 0 0.25rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: inherit;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.horizontal-tabs a:hover, .horizontal-tabs a:focus, .horizontal-tabs a.active {
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
  border-bottom-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.horizontal-tabs a + * {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

.content-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-top: 3rem;
  margin-top: -1px;
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
}

.content-header-intro h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.content-header-intro p {
  color: var(--c-text-secondary);
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-header-actions a:first-child {
    display: none;
  }
}

.content {
  border-top: 1px solid var(--c-border-primary);
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.content-panel {
  display: none;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 0;
  margin-right: 3rem;
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .content-panel {
    display: block;
  }
}

.vertical-tabs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.vertical-tabs a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.75em 1em;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-radius: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.vertical-tabs a:hover, .vertical-tabs a:focus, .vertical-tabs a.active {
  background-color: var(--c-background-tertiary);
  color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.vertical-tabs a + * {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.content-main {
  padding-top: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.card-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  -moz-column-gap: 1.5rem;
       column-gap: 1.5rem;
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .card-grid {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

.card {
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.25rem 1rem 1.25rem;
}
.card-header div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-header div span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.card-header div span img {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.card-header div h3 {
  margin-left: 0.75rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.toggle span {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 99em;
  background-color: var(--c-background-quaternary);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle span:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 3px;
  top: 3px;
  height: 18px;
  width: 18px;
  background-color: var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: 0.15s ease;
}
.toggle input {
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(50%);
          clip-path: inset(50%);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
.toggle input:checked + span {
  background-color: var(--c-accent-primary);
}
.toggle input:checked + span:before {
  transform: translateX(calc(100% - 2px));
}
.toggle input:focus + span {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px var(--c-background-tertiary);
}

.card-body {
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

.card-footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  padding: 1rem 1.25rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.125);
}
.card-footer a {
  color: var(--c-text-action);
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--c-text-primary);
  border: 4px solid var(--c-background-primary);
  border-radius: 99em;
}
```

Comment: Your html have several errors. Use this tool to validate your html: https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea. You have some closing tags that don't have matching opening tags.

Answer (score 0):

You are using Bootstrap 5, yet you did not linked it in the head:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Then change the structure of your Navbar:

```
    <!---Navbar--->
<header>

    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Logo Here</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#mainmenu">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainmenu">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Page</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown 01</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" class="dropdown-item">Dropdown 02</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<!---Navbar--->
```

And finally, remove the custom CSS you made in your CSS file. Eventually, in the css file, search for Nav and delete everything related to the navbar

Comment: When I add the bootstrap css link it messes up the rest of my page's styling

Comment: I want to keep the same styling for my nav but have different style for the rest of the page

Comment: That's why I had took it out

Comment: or how can I override the bootstrap css so that i just styles the nav and not my body's content? I have updated my question to show what it does to my page when I add it